# SQL ON statement : PK or FK on the left as a convention?

Tags: sql, join, foreign-keys, primary-key

I am curious about if there is a convention in **SQL** that encourages us to use the **Primary Key** or the **Foreign Key** on the left after an **ON** statement.

I mean, lets assume that we have two tables called *MASTER* and *DETAIL*. And *DETAIL* has a **foreign key** that targets master.

so is there any convention that leads us to a desicion between

```
MASTER m inner join DETAIL d on m.ID = d.MASTER_ID
```

and

```
MASTER m inner join DETAIL d on d.MASTER_ID = m.ID
```

Comment: It makes no actual difference. Remember that in SQL you're telling the system *what to do*, not *how to do it*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever absolutely. That why i ask if there is any convention

Comment: It might be `[Detail] As d INNER JOIN [Master] As m` as well. I don't know if there's any convention but im always trying to stick *first in join first in equality check* convention, as you presented

Comment: I'm with Zefnus there - given the existence of `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN` which imply a left side and a right side to every join, I just try to ensure that the left table is referenced on the left of the join conditions, and the same for the right table.

Comment: Use whatever order you like, but be consistent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no convention in using a primary key or a foreign key on the left after an `ON` statement for a `JOIN`. The SQL Engine, as pointed out @Damien_The_Unbeliever, doesn't *ask you how to fetch data*, but *which data you want to fetch*.

Then, it's irrelevant on using first a primary or a foreign key on the left after an `ON` statement.

Comment: No, those two statements are the same. `MASTER` is always the left table and `DETAIL` is always the right table. The placement of the conditions in the `ON` is irrelevant.